# What is the probability she stops her walk after walking exactly eight blocks?

Tags: probability

> Gracie starts at her house and walks one block east. After each block she walks, she flips a fair coin. She walks one block east if the coin lands heads; otherwise one block west. She stops her walk the first time she lands back at home. What is the probability she stops her walk after walking exactly eight blocks? Express your answer as a common fraction?

I solved this by letting a $1$ denote a block east and a $-1$ denote a block west. Thus we have $1 (111-1-1-1-1)$ where we can order the things in parenthesis any $\dfrac{7!}{3!*4!}$ ways. Thus, the answer I got was $\dfrac{\dfrac{7!}{3!*4!}}{2^7} = \dfrac{35}{128}$. However, the answer key disagrees and says the answer is $\dfrac{5}{128}$.

Comment: What you've calculated is the ways you end up at home after 8 steps. This includes cases where you leave home and then come back (which are not valid in the context of the problem).

Comment: How should I count this then?

Comment: I need to count the number of sequences AAABBBB where there cannot appear $n$ number of A's and $n+1$ number of B's in one segment of the sequence.

Comment: Well, you know the last step has to be a west (else you've hit the house before). So, you need to find lists of length 6 where you have 3 easts and 3 wests (else you can't end at 1 block east and then reach home) such that you have taken at least as many easts as wests. You can look up Bertrand's ballot theorem and see how it relates to this.

Comment: I think it is different, though. I could do $EWWEEW$, which doesn't satisfy the question but satisfies what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ denote a step east and $W$ denote a block west. A move sequence returns us home if it consists of 4 E's and 4 W's. Notice that since the first move needs to be $E,$ the second move must be $E$ else Gracie will go back home. So, our sequences must start $EE.$ From here we have two cases. Either the next move is $E$ or $W:$

- $EEW$: The next move cannot be $W$ else Gracie will go back home. So the next move has to be $E.$ Our sequence so far is $EEWE.$ The next move can be either $E$ or $W$ so we have 2 subcases: $EEWEE$ or $EEWEW.$ In the first subcase we are done since we have used up all the E's, so that leaves the sequence $\boxed{EEWEEWWW}.$ In the second subcase, the next move can't be $W$ else we will go back home, so it has to be $E.$ So our sequence is $EEWEWE.$ Since we have used up all the $E$'s, or sequence is $\boxed{EEWEWEWW}.$
- $EEE$: The next move can either by $E$ or $W.$ So we have two cases, $EEEE$ or $EEEW.$ In the first case, we are done, since we have used up the 4 $E$'s. That case ends as $\boxed{EEEEWWWW}.$ In the second case, the next move can either be $E$ or $W.$ So the second case has 2 subcases, $EEEWE$ or $EEEWW.$ In the first subcase we are done since we have exhausted all the E's, leaving $\boxed{EEEWEWWW}.$ In the second subcase, the next character can only be $E$ else Gracie goes back home, leaving the sequence $\boxed{EEEWWEWW}.$

Thus there are 5 possible move sequences which satisfy the condition. There are $2^7=128$ total move sequences which begin with $E.$ Thus our answer is $\boxed{\tfrac{5}{128}}.$

Note: Contact me on AoPS if you have any questions (user:jeff2002).

Answer (score 0):

There are just 5 possible sequences starting with EE and ending with WW that are acceptable, each with probability of 1/128. Let me know if this hint is not enough to solve the problem and will detail the 5 sequences.

Comment: Please show me how to list all $5$.

Comment: EEWEWEWW, EEWEEWWW, EEEWEWWW, EEEWWEWW, and EEEEWWWW. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Thought that after you specifically asked for you will "pay" with accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Count ways of proceeding 4 blocks E and 4 N w/o touching the main diagonal till the end.

x - x - x - x - 5

x - x - x - x - 5

x - x - x - 2 - 5

x - x - 1 - 2 - 3

0 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1